# How to get a part of a var in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my function, I have the following var (Its content is a html code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html class="no-js" lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css"></link>
  <title>App Android</title>
 </head>
 <form action="#" class="formulario" name="formulario">
 <style>
     .campo-texto {
         color: #7B7D7D;
         height: 30px;
         position: absolute;
         padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
         border-style: ridge;
         resize: horizontal;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         overflow-y: hidden;
         background-color: white;
         text-align: left;
         border-radius: 6px;
     }
     .campo-botao {
         position: absolute;
         height: 28px;
         width: 80px;
         border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
         text-align: center;
         border-radius: 6px;
         box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
         overflow: hidden;
     }
     .campo-prompt {
         position: absolute;
         min-height: 20px;
         display: inline-block;
         padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
         border: 1px dotted black;
         border-radius: 6px;
     }
     .a9-screen-dimension {
         position: relative;
         margin: 0px;
         width: 340px;
         height: 540px;
         border: 1px solid black;
         background-color: #CED7E5;
         overflow: hidden;
         }
 </style>
 <body>
 <div id="myScreen" class="a9-screen-dimension" tabindex="0">     
   <div id="promptId0" class="campo-prompt" draggable="true" style="top:68.625px; left:65.84375px;" tabindex="0">Prompt</div><button id="botaoId1" class="campo-botao" draggable="true" style="top:235.625px; left:77.84375px;" tabindex="0" myselection="salvar">Salvar</div></div>
 </div>
 </form>
 <script>
  function send(toast) {
   var cod = formulario.cod.value;
   Android.sendDataToAndroid(cod);
  }
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, I just need to get just the following part:

```
<div id="myScreen" class="a9-screen-dimension" tabindex="0">
 <div id="promptId0" class="campo-prompt" draggable="true"  style="top:68.625px; left:65.84375px;" tabindex="0">Prompt</div><button id="botaoId1" class="campo-botao" draggable="true" style="top:235.625px;left:77.84375px;" tabindex="0" myselection="salvar">Salvar</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I already tried the followins ways, but all of then give me the error: "...is not a function...".

```
reader = reader.substr(reader.indexOf('<div id=\"myScreen\"'), reader.length() - 132);
```

```
reader = reader.substr(reader.indexOf('<div id=\"myScreen\"'), reader.indexOf('</form>'));
```

The content inside div myScreen is generated dynamically, so it may be bigger or smaller than the example.

I am reading this content from a .html file.

This is my function:

```
$("#openProject").on("click", function openProject()

{
    $("#inputAbrir").trigger('click');
    inputAbrir.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var file = inputAbrir.files[0];

    if (file.name.match(/\.(html)$/)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function() {

            console.log(reader.result);

        };
        reader.readAsText(file);    
    } 
    else {
        alert("Just .HTML files are supported!");
    }
   });
});
```

Maybe I am wrong, but I think that, since I already have the content of the var, I just need to find a way to get a part of its content right? I just don't figure it out yet...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try $(document).ready(function() { console.log($("#myScreen")[0]); });

Comment: Hello @mbadeveloper. As I am reading a string, this just not works. I am still trying!

Comment: its return the complete content of the myScreen div. I think that what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing is to parse it as HTML, then you can use DOM methods to read and manipulate it:

```js
// mock reader
const reader = {};
reader.result = getHTML();

const parser = new DOMParser();
const domobj = parser.parseFromString(reader.result, "text/html");
const myScreenHTML = domobj.querySelector("#myScreen").outerHTML;
console.log(myScreenHTML);

    const expression = /(<div id="myScreen"[\s\S]*?<\/div>\s*<\/form>)/im;
    console.log(expression.exec(reader.result)[1]);

function getHTML() {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css"></link>
<title>App Android</title>
</head>
<form action="#" class="formulario" name="formulario">
<style>
     .campo-texto {
         color: #7B7D7D;
         height: 30px;
         position: absolute;
         padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
         border-style: ridge;
         resize: horizontal;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         overflow-y: hidden;
         background-color: white;
         text-align: left;
         border-radius: 6px;
     }
     .campo-botao {
         position: absolute;
         height: 28px;
         width: 80px;
         border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
         text-align: center;
         border-radius: 6px;
         box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
         overflow: hidden;
     }
     .campo-prompt {
         position: absolute;
         min-height: 20px;
         display: inline-block;
         padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
         border: 1px dotted black;
         border-radius: 6px;
     }
     .a9-screen-dimension {
         position: relative;
         margin: 0px;
         width: 340px;
         height: 540px;
         border: 1px solid black;
         background-color: #CED7E5;
         overflow: hidden;
         }
</style>
<body>
<div id="myScreen" class="a9-screen-dimension" tabindex="0">     
   <div id="promptId0" class="campo-prompt" draggable="true" style="top:68.625px; left:65.84375px;" tabindex="0">Prompt</div><button id="botaoId1" class="campo-botao" draggable="true" style="top:235.625px; left:77.84375px;" tabindex="0" myselection="salvar">Salvar</div></div>
</div>
</form>
<${"script"}>
function send(toast) {
  var cod = formulario.cod.value;
  Android.sendDataToAndroid(cod);
}
</${"script"}>
</body>
</html>`;
}
```

#### Not recommended:

You may also use a regular expression. Since you insisted, here's how:

```
const expression = /(<div id="myScreen"[\s\S]*?<\/div>\s*<\/form>)/im;
console.log(expression.exec(reader.result)[1]);
```

Here's a fiddle for the regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/jwyCPh/1

Comment: Hello @Tomas. I will test this. But, just for information, is there anyway to get this just by treating the var somehow? I am asking because I thought: I already have the string, so now how can I get just that part of it. I am still trying!

Comment: For limited cases, it is possible to use regular expression. But I advise against it - you might get all kinds of problems when the HTML changes that would not occur if you parse it and query it as HTML. You can try to google why not to use regular expressions for HTML.

Comment: I see... But, don't you know any way I can try to treat the string and get that information? For example, instead of the html content, I had the var: "12345<div>random content</div>54321". How could I get just the div and its content?

Comment: @Vhox Why do you insist on getting the string that way? Unless there's a reason not to, always use HTML parser. I'll add answer you seek, but I really don't recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas! That is exactly what I needed! Actually, I need to get that part to insert in another function in my application! I really apreciate your advices! Thanks!

Comment: I still implore you to use real DOM parsing. Parsing the strin ga sregular expression is a foolish decision. Please consider the fact that I have written many JS applications and I am speaking from experience.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you showed is invalid. I fixed that.

Is `outerHTML` maybe what you are looking for?

```js
console.log(myScreen.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="myScreen" class="a9-screen-dimension" tabindex="0">
  <div id="promptId0" class="campo-prompt" draggable="true" style="top:68.625px; left:65.84375px;" tabindex="0">Prompt</div><button id="botaoId1" class="campo-botao" draggable="true" style="top:235.625px; left:77.84375px;" tabindex="0" myselection="salvar">Salvar</button></div>
```

Comment: hello @conexxo. As I am reading the content of a var, and I need a part of it, the outerHTML does not work. I just do not figure out how to get that part of the string yet. I am still trying!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the variable string to pare it to HTML and do the selection of the div after that:

```
var yourPage= $.parseHTML(pageString);
var myScreenDiv= $(yourPage).find("#myScreen");
console.log(myScreenDiv.outerHTML);
```